# Ruby/Sinatra: Passing a URL variable to an .erb template

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I'm using Padrino, and I want to take parameters out of URL and use them in an `.erb` template.

In my app setup I have:

```
get '/testpage/:id' do
  userID = params[:id]
  render 'test/index'
end
```

In my `test/` folder I have `index.html.erb` which is successfully rendered, for a url like `http://localhost:9000/testpage/hello123`.

However, I've tried printing the `params[:userID]` on the page with:

```
<%= @userID %>
```

The rest of the page renders fine but `hello123` isn't anywhere to be found. When I try `<%= userID %>` I get `` undefined local variable or method `userID' for #<stuff> ``

What am I missing here?

Comment: Change title: it's padrino specific, not sinatra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, because I've never used Padrino, but if it works like Rails this may help you:

```
get '/testpage/:id' do
  @userID = params[:id]
  render 'test/index'
end
```

Comment: That was annoyingly simple to fix. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it was easy, @Jascination!

Answer (score 0):

In sinatra, it's just [like](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html) this (see "Views/Templates" section):

```
get '/testpage/:id' do |id|
  erb :index, :locals => {:id => id}
end
```

The template is located in `views/index.erb` by default. It could be change.